# Laravel 5.3: localhost redirected you too many times

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have 2 user roles which is `superadmin` and `admin`

I don't want `admin` to access of Settings Page.

I am not sure if this is the proper way.

---

So, here's my SettingsController.php

```
class SettingsController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        if(Auth::user()->roles == 0) {
            return redirect(url()->previous());
        } else {
            return view('settings.index');
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see if the `roles` is 0. I redirect the user to the last page they're in. I also tried to use `return back()`;

---

web.php (routes)

```
<?php

Route::get('/', ['uses' => 'UsersController@index']);
Route::post('login', ['uses' => 'UsersController@login']);

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
    Route::get('logout', ['uses' => 'UsersController@destroy']);
    Route::get('upline', ['uses' => 'UplinesController@index']);
    Route::get('upline/create', ['uses' => 'UplinesController@create']);
    Route::post('upline', ['uses' => 'UplinesController@store']);
    Route::delete('upline/destroy/{id}', ['uses' => 'UplinesController@destroy']);
    Route::put('upline/update/{id}', ['uses' => 'UplinesController@update']);
    Route::get('upline/getdownlines/{id}', ['uses' => 'UplinesController@getDownlines']);

    Route::get('downline', ['uses' => 'DownlinesController@index']);
    Route::post('downline', ['uses' => 'DownlinesController@store']);
    Route::delete('upline/destroy/{id}', ['uses' => 'DownlinesController@destroy']);
    Route::put('downline/update/{id}', ['uses' => 'DownlinesController@update']);

    Route::get('bonus', ['uses' => 'BonusController@index']);
    Route::post('bonus/csv', ['uses' => 'BonusController@fileUpload']);

    Route::get('settings', ['uses' => 'SettingsController@index']);
});
```

I have a 2nd question. Can I limit admin using middleware? If yes, how?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're trying to redirect to the previous page which in turn will hit the middleware that will try to limit the access by redirecting to the previous page...do you see where I'm going with this? It's a redirect loop. Try redirecting to the index or some other predefined route.

Comment: @Andrew It worked in predefined route. But the program needs to get back to the previous url.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, you can "hack" your way around the loop by redirecting with an error and checking if the error exists in the middleware. If it does, stop the redirect and simply display the page. Just so we're clear, this isn't exactly and ideal solution but to be prefectly honest nothing else comes to mind at the moment.

Comment: @Andrew I tried to remove the middleware. Still having the same error when using back();

Comment: It's very hard to tell what's wrong by only looking at the code you posted, not your fault, Laravel does a ton of stuff before hitting the routes. I'd suggest installing xDebug and tracing the calls to the routes. It will give you an idea of what route is to blame.

Comment: @Andrew thanks man. I'll look at it.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to message me again if you need help. I usually stick around the questions I've commented on.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the second option, "**Limiting admin with middleware**".
So you can try something like;

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'DownlinesController@update');
});
```

Then

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'super', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'UplinesController@index');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As @michael s answer suggests use middleware, his answer fails to demonstrate on how to do it (mine too, I just added more text).

> **Note**: Laravel is big because of its documentation, **USE IT**!

You have 2 (or more options):

- parameterized middleware
- 2 distinctive middlewares (one for admin, another for superadmin)

> **Note**: use artisan to generate middleware from stubs, `$ php artisan make:middleware MyNewShinyMiddleware`

### parametrized middleware (my pick)

Head to documentation and check out [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#middleware-parameters).

Example shows exactly your problem.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
{
    if (! $request->user()->hasRole($role)) { //implement hasRole in User Model
        // Redirect... 
        // (use named routes to redirect or do 401 (unauthorized) because thats what is going on!
        // abort(401) // create view in /views/errors/401.blade.php
        // return redirect()->route('home');
    }

    //success user has role $role, do nothing here just go to another "onion" layer
    return $next($request);
}
```

### 2 distinctive middlewares

simply create two middlewares and hardcode your checking routine of roles
(same as you do in your controller sample) except use `$request->user()`...

---

**(routes) web.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'role:admin'], function () {...} //parametrized

Route::group(['middleware' => 'checkRoleAdmin'], function () {...}
Route::group(['middleware' => 'checkRoleSuper'], function () {...}
```

> **Note**: `role`, `checkRoleAdmin` and `checkRoleSuper` are "named" middlewares and you need to register them in kernel.php

---

Another way is yo use gates or policies which make the best sense, since you are trying to limit user. Read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authorization).

I use middleware based [ACL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) for really simple projects (like one admin and no real users).
I use gates based ACL for medium projects (1-2 roles).
I use policies based ACL for "huge" projects (many roles, many users).

Also consider looking at https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust